# Advanced Visual Studio RegEx Replace

Tags: xml, regex, visual-studio, replace

I have multiple sections with id's.

```
<section id="01"></section>
<section id="02"></section>
<section id="03"></section>
```

What I would like to do is match and replace all these id's with itself + 1, i.e 1 becomes 2, 2 becomes 3, etc.

I have gotten as far as:

```
find:
id="{[0-9][0-9]}"
--
replace:
\0
```

Comment: ugh - I shudder to call the Visual Studio search syntax an actual regular expression (even if it _technically_ is)... blech!

Comment: oh yeah - this absolutely cannot be done reliably with normal regex implementations (including... <shudder>... Visual Studio), even though there are tricks that MIGHT work to a certain extent in certain, very limited situations... kinda...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add last and delete first entry.

Or you can match two entries at once and use backrefs, if they are not continius id's, but just random numbers.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work... in the end I just used decimals.

e.g.
    `<section id="2"></section>
    <section id="2.1"></section>
    <section id="3"></section>`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use RegEx.

Load it up using XmlDocument and use XPath.  Something like:

```
Dim tDoc as XmlDocument = New XmlDocument(xmlfilename)
For Each tNode As XmlNode In tDoc.SelectNodes("//sections/section")
  tNode.Attributes("id").Value = String.Format("{0:D2}", Int16.Parse(tNode.Attributes("id").Value) + 1)
Next

tDoc.Save(path)
```

Comment: Yeah, I don't think regex (at least in VS' search and replace) has the capability to perform math on results... only simple replaces.

Comment: @danyim: you could do some kind of bastardized loop over the regex matches, starting with the last match and working your way forward.  But man that'd be ugly.